# Xamarin.Build.Download package issue on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, maps

I am facing an issue while building Xamarin.iOS project in Xamarin.Forms project.

**Current Packages:**
I added latest versions of Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps, Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps and Xamarin.Build.Downloads

**Error while Building:**
Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(3,3): Error: Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Google.Maps, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

**What I tried?**
1- Delete bin/obj directories, reopening and rebuilding project
2- Tried downgrading package versions
3- Targeted iOS Deployment greater than 9

Comment: Make sure that  the version of XF both in share project and iOS project are up to date . And install the package in iOS project instead of the share project .

Comment: XF versions are same in all projects. I also tried by only installing it(Xamarin.Build.Download) in iOS project. But no luck.

Comment: You could create a new blank project and install the package to check if the issue still exists . It is a common issue which maybe caused by your project configuration .

Comment: did you find a solution, same issue - seeing it all over the web with no real answer